# Is it Okay to have Entities in Core Data with no relation with any other entities?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsuserdefaults

Is it Okay to move whatever information we store in NSUserDefaults to CoreData ?
Generally we store some user settings kind of data , or user's information in NSUserDefault,

If we store this in a single entity as a key-value pair, does it have any performance hit ?

Or is it a bad practice as such.

I find it weird to have all data related to app in Core Data and logged-in user's information in NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its logged in user information it should probably be in the keychain.

You can have an entity with no relationships, there's nothing to prevent it, but accessing those details will now require that you open the model store file. If you only need them when the store is open then not too much of a problem. The process of extracting the entity instance is still a fetch request so constitutes more code than the NSUserDefaults option.

There's no hard and fast rule, each area of data storage is more useful for access at different times and you should expect to use each of them in your app. You should also consider how long the data should be retained and how many copies you need (now, and potentially in the future).

Generally, for user account details I'd hold them outside the Core Data model.

Comment: So when a scenario arrives where you cache user details of other user's say a some friends in a social network app in core data as user-profile details of them, so that we dont load them every now and then.

In such cases I feel like the logged-in user's profile details can be modeled as the same entity as other user's profiel details being cached and find a way to differentiate it from others.

How do we work in this case ?

Comment: In this case you *could* have a user entity and store all user details there in the store file, and tag the current user or hold the current user id in NSUserDefaults so you can use it to fetch the main user. You don't really need relationships between the users if they're all just friends. What shouldn't be in the data store is any password / auth token.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was really helpful. passwords I don't store at all. In case of a session expiry, I either present the login screen again or if possible have the token refreshed with a refresh token.

These tokens, should be in KeyChain only ? or UserDefaults is fine?

Comment: Tokens should really be held only in memory or stored in the keychain. Not in user defaults.